# Passing data from Fragment to FragmentActivity not functioning

Tags: android, event-handling, fragment

I'm not sure why the code I have set up isn't working correctly.

I am trying to start an activity and pass some data when the intent is called to open the activity.

For some reason, this isn't working as planned and when I click my list item to open up an activity, just a blank black screen comes up, this shouldn't happen and my data passing isn't being passed correctly.

here's my code, hopefully someone can guide me in the correct direction.

Calling code:

```
    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    if (position == 0) {

        String msg = "First";
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageGridActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("1", msg);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if (position == 1) {

        String msg = "Second";
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageGridActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("2", msg);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Handling class:

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String Abstract = "Abstract";
private static final String Animal = "Animal";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Utils.enableStrictMode();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String msg = extras.getString("KeyMessage");

    if (msg == "1") {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Abstract) == null) {
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, new AbstractGridFragment(),
                    Abstract);
            ft.commit();

        }

        if (msg == "2") {

        }
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Animal) == null) {
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, new AnimalGridFragment(), Animal);
            ft.commit();
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: also where is your `setContentView` for FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys don't match

```
    String msg = extras.getString("KeyMessage");
```

While your keys are "1" and "2"

Check the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

`public Intent putExtra (String name, String value)`

Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Parameters

```
name    The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
value   The String data value.
```

Returns

```
Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.
```

You probably want

```
   Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageGridActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("key", "1"); // "key" is the key and "1" is the value
   startActivity(i);
```

and

```
   Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageGridActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("key", "2");
   startActivity(i);
```

Then

```
   String msg = extras.getString("key");
```

Also use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings

```
   if (msg.equals("1")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrong in key send/reception. You should try like this:

Instante your String `msg`

```
String msg;
```

if

```
msg = "1";
i.putExtra("myKey", msg);
```

else

```
msg = "2";
i.putExtra("myKey", msg);
```

So:

```
String msg = extras.getString("myKey");
if("1".equals(msg)) // so...
else if("2".equals(msg)) // so...
```

Hope this help.